# reflection need help. cubeCamera lookAt

Tags: 3d, three.js

My object is tetrahedral, and I'm doing reflections inside tetrahedral, it's a triangular pyramid, I think the Cube Camera can't work correct for triangular pyramid, because the cube Camera faces doesn't perpendicular with vertex of tetrahedral, so the cases is not same as cube or sphere or torus, am I correct?

do I need to implement a similar camera as cubecamera? the reason I ask this is: when I go inside from a vertex, I can see the vertex in the middle of the opposite face, but if I go inside from another vertex it isn't in the middle of opposite face.
see: http://www.novaui.com/dc/viewer%20-%20v3.html

Answer (score 2):

CubeCamera should work. CubeCamera generate cubemaps and those work for any kind of shape.

You need to hide the object that you want to have to have reflecting when rendering from the CubeCamera. That's what these *cough*s mean :)

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2.html#L205